# datalogic usb oem HID mode

Tags: barcode-scanner, javapos

I have datalogic qd2131 hand scanner, want to use with java pos
after scanning the interface usb-oem the scanner dies 
please help in enabling the scanner

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time ago in a galaxy far far away ....

but disconnect device, hold 5 sec trigger, connect device. Release trigger. Some seconds it will be flashing. Then reconnect device.